# Stuck on Format specifier

Tags: python, python-3.6

I was going through [this](http://monik.in/a-noobs-guide-to-implementing-rnn-lstm-using-tensorflow/) tutorial on making a RNN LSTM network and I came across this format specifier:

```
'{0:020b}'.format(i)
```

the expected output is a 20 character long string of 0's and 1's but I can't seem to figure out why and how this specifier works.

Could anyone explain this?

Cheers

Comment: The first digit is the character to use for padding. The remainder of the digits form a number that specifies the field width. The last character is the number system (binary here).

Comment: Here's a pretty good introduction to python formatting: https://pyformat.info/

Comment: [Here are the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)